# Docker flask app request origin header removed

Tags: docker, vue.js, flask, docker-compose

I'm building an app using a webpack/vue based approach for the frontend (served using nginx after a build) and a Flask app as the backend. Both are contained in separate Docker containers and can communicate by means building a network using a docker-compose file.

Everything works well except for one thing: the Docker containers have different ports and are therefore categorized as cross origins, meaning that responses from the backend can only be read if the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `*`. I do this in Flask using:

```
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    header = response.headers
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'content-type, session_id'
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT'
    return response
```

Which works perfectly: when I run the backend en frontend outside their Docker containers, the response headers actually container my set header.

But in the Docker container, somehow the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` gets removed from the Flask response.

Here are my docker files and the docker-compose file:

Backend:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install pipenv

COPY ./backend /app

# Pipfile and Pipfile.lock needed with --system flag
COPY ./backend/Pipfile /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/uploads

# RUN pipenv lock && pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
RUN pipenv install --system --deploy --skip-lock

EXPOSE 5000

# Run the app
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

Frontend:

```
# Stage 1: Build
FROM node AS build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install all dependencies for production
COPY frontend/package.json .
RUN npm install

ENV NODE_ENV="production"

# Bundle app source
COPY frontend/ .
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2: Production environment
FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy built VUE app to be served by nginx
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Docker compose:

```
version : '3'

services:
  frontend:
    image: ***
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.frontend
    image: ***
    ports:
      - "9080:80"
    networks:
      - app_net

  backend:
    image: ***
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.backend
    image: ***
    networks:
      - app_net
    ports:
      - "6852:6852"
    expose:
      - "6852"

# Build internal network, otherwise frontend and backend
# can't communicate on MacOS
networks:
  app_net:
    driver: "bridge"
```

Any ideas to set the CORS header manually or make sure it isn't removed?

Comment: how is nginx configuration in nginx container ?

Comment: It's the default. I simply use the nginx:alpine image.